# Display fallback image even if the browser supports html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

This might sound strange, but can I still display fallback image in that case?

Since video elements in mobile (Android & iOS) will open its native video player app when clicked, I want to show GIF version of the video (which I will place as the fallback image) for Android & iOS. I know how to detect whether the browser is mobile or not via Javascript, I just need some advice on best practice.

What I'm doing

```
<video>
    <source mp4>
    <source ogg>
    <source webm>
    <img src="*.gif">
</video>
```

Then in the js

```
if(site.isMobile()){
    $('video').hide();
    $('video img').show();
}
```

Of course it doesn't work since the img is inside video. I figure I can clone the img and append it before the video element and then hide the video element, something like this :

```
if(site.isMobile()){
    $('video img').clone().prependTo('video'); // just some pseudocode
    $('video').hide();
}
```

Is it a good practice though? Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: How can people favorite the questions without upvoting it? This questions is clear and asking a reoccurring problem.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`poster` may be what you're looking for:

> **Poster**: A URL indicating a poster frame to show until the user plays or seeks. If this attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until the first frame is available; then the first frame is displayed as the poster frame. -Via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/video

#### Example:

```html
<video width="316" height="161" poster="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfXRi.png" controls>
  <source src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct: it's cleaner and doesn't depend on JavaScript.

Comment: ^ No, the original question was to display the (poster) image even if video is supported

Comment: Works great, especially for apple devices as they very kindly removed the 'autoplay' functionality :/

Comment: @JDavies depending on what you're trying to do, autoplay is still available. If you mute the video it's still usable.

Comment: The videos are completely blocked from autoplaying in mobile devices now.l And the poster doesn't show, instead it shows the first frame of the video but paused.

Comment: Does this work for iOS 9? I need to use autoplay for the  browsers which supports autoplay but since iOS 9 does not support it I need to show an image set on poster.

Answer (score 5):

Try this-

```
if(site.isMobile()){
    $('video *').hide();
    $('video img').show();
}
```

rather than creating a copy of the image.

Comment: Is this real code, or pseudo-code? Where's the `site.isMobile()` coming from?